# Char variable minus char variable parse to Int in java

Tags: java, parsing, char

I know this is trivial, but I can't find the proper explication. I have the following code

```
str="1230"
int rez=str.charAt(3) - '0';
rez=3;
```

How does this parsing work?

Comment: What is the problem? (beside, char are more or less integer, and arithmetic work on them, that's why you can do c - '0'.

Comment: "How does this parsing work?" - Are you asking how the language parser parses that source code?

Comment: Maybe you should dive deeper into basics of how computers work and what is needed to display a digit or letter on your screen. A start could be here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: @NoDataFound - please see my comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the character is a digit, you can get the equivalent `int` value by subtracting `'0'`.  The ASCII coding for `'0'` is decimal `48`, `'1'` is decimal `49`, etc.

`So '8' - '0' = 56 - 48 = 8;`

For your number, you can parse the entire string like this (assuming all the characters are digits, otherwise the result wouldn't make sense).

```
String v = "1230";
int result = 0; // starting point
for (int i = 0; i < v.length(); i++) {
    result = result* 10 + v.charAt(i) -'0';
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
1230
```

Explanation

```
In the above loop, first time thru
result = 0 * 10 + '1'-'0 = 1
second time thru 
result = 1 * 10  + '2'-'0' = 12
third time thru 
result = 12 * 10  + '3'-'0' = 123
last time thru 
result = 123 * 10  + '0'-'0' = 1230
```

Answer (score -1):

"Behind the scene" a `char` is just an int with a specific range (very simplified explanation).

Try following code to convince yourself:

```java
System.out.println((int) '0'); // this won't output 0
System.out.println((int) 'a'); // this work as well
```

This is why arithmetic operations are possible on `char`s.

Comment: This is misleading when the OP is clearly attempting to do arithmetic on `char` data types. For example, change the OP's input string to "123A" and perform the same arithmetic operation as in the OP's question. The result is non-sensicle. Perhaps you should point that out?

Comment: Behind the scenes a `char` is an UTF-16 character represented in a couple different ways - one of those ways is as an integer value that represents a specific UTF-16 character.

Comment: Sure @randy, feel free to edit my answer as I'm not sure to understand why it's misleading